# is it possible to send a not requested info or command to clients in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

in a Silverlight application, we used to send requests from client to server and receive its response.
is it possible to send an information from server to client which is not waiting for? for example server ask client to update a text in a special text box and so on. "an info or known command which may come to client any time and is not a response to the client's request"?

Comment: you could do that easily with SignalR https://github.com/SignalR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) for this.